# Adding values in C using inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

Im trying to get a grasp on the basics of inline assembly in C (ATT assembly), so Im practicing by adding 2 variables.

Ok so this works as intended; the *src* variable gets copied to the *dst* variable and then the *dst* variable gets added by 5. The values of *src* and *dst* are 1 and 6 respectively.

```
int src = 1;
int dst = 0;

asm ("mov %[SRC], %[DEST]\n\t"
     "add $5, %0"
     : [DEST] "=r" (dst));
     : [SRC] "r" (src));
```

But when I try this out, the values of *src* and *dst* are still 1 and 6. I was expecting *src* to have the value 1 and *dst* to have the value 5 since adding 5 to *dst* (which has the value of 0 since the MOV operation has been removed) should have the output 5.

int src = 1;
   int dst = 0;

```
 asm ("add $5, %[DEST]"
     : [DEST] "=r" (dst)
     : [SRC] "r" (src));
```

So I then try removing the *src* as an input operand using the following code, but now *dst* gets the value 11.

```
int dst = 0;

     asm (
         "add $5, %[DEST]"
         : [DEST] "=r" (dst));
```

Now I'm a bit confused how it works. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: I just compiled your last example, it gives dst=5, not 11. Maybe you are compiling/executing something different?

Comment: @Inspired I double checked and it really gives 11 :(

Comment: Could you provide a complete program, with main()? Maybe it's something with how you print the value, or there is something else happening, apart from the snippet and a call to printf/cout.

Comment: @Inspired http://pastebin.com/HLXtvbRw i made a new program since the original code is for a kernel and would have additional complications

Comment: Gcc inline asm is a complicated beast, sometimes even incorrect code seems to work which then fails under different circumstances. If you really need it, be prepared to use the `-S` switch to see generated assembly code so you can see what the compiler produces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first part of your code works as expected. There

```
 mov %[SRC], %[DEST]        ; copies %[SRC] into %[DEST], which is now 1
 add $5, %0                 ; adds 5 to %0 (which is %[DEST]), so that's 6
```

The second part does not work because you never use `%[SRC]`, and because `%[DEST]` is not an input operand, so its value doesn't come into the calculation. You just get what happens to be in the register gcc decides to use. The third part fails for the same reason.

For it to work, you need to specify `dst` as both an input and output operand, since you're both using its value and changing it. However, this does not work:

```
asm("add $5, %0"  // This does not work!
    : "=r" (dst)
    : "r" (dst));
```

because now you have an input operand `%1` with value `dst` and a distinct output operand `%0` whose value will be written to `dst`, and you never use `%1`. This notation would allow you to write

```
asm("mov %1, %0; add $5, %0"  // needlessly inefficient!
    : "=r" (dst)
    : "r" (dst));
```

but that is, of course, needlessly inefficient. In order to do this with a single register, you need to use a **matching constraint** like this:

```
asm("add $5, %0"
    : "=r" (dst)
    : "0" (dst));
```

This tells gcc that `%0` as an input operand is allowed, and that it has the value of `dst`. [Here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Simple-Constraints.html) is the relevant part of the gcc manual.

With named operands, finally, it looks like this:

```
asm ("add $5, %[DEST]"
     : [DEST] "=r" (dst)
     : "[DEST]" (dst));
```

Comment: But for the first example, there is an operation ADD $1, [DEST] after the MOV operation, it works even though dst is not an input operand? Im a bit confused on that part.

Comment: In my test, the first one gave the expected value with `-O2` but not without it, so it's kind of playing Russian roulette with the optimizer. It is not guaranteed to work, in any case. You get what happened to be in the register it decides to use, and that may or may not be one that already contains `dst`.

Comment: whats -02? Is adding dst to the output operators along with src in the first case  (while still being in the output operands) the best way to go?

Comment: I meant the `-O2` option to gcc, which controls the level of optimization.

Comment: I edited in a bit about the first case, and why the results it gives are expected.

Comment: you mentioned in your comment that the first case is not guaranteed to work without -02, how can it be guaranteed to work then?

Comment: I misread what you wrote; I was referring to my own first case.

Comment: It's generally easier to use an inout constraint (`+`) rather than out constraint + match.  With that you need just `asm("add $5,%[DEST]" : [DEST] "+r" (dst));`